# Find records related to other records in controller (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm grabbing a list of users and storing in `@users`.

Now I need to find properties related to only this list of users I have queried.

```
 if params[:company].present?
      @users = User.where(parent_id: params[:company]).or(User.where(id: params[:company]))
      #@properties = @properties.where(user_id: params[:company])
    end
```

I would basically like to include `@users` inside `@properties.where()`

I need to get each property that has a user_id present in my `@users` array

edit:

I just did the following which gives me the result, however, I'm sure there's a much better way of doing this via activerecord:

```
      ids = []
      @users.each do |user|
        ids.push(user.id)
      end
      @properties = @properties.where(user_id: ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@properties.where(user_id: @users.ids)
```

That should work. It'll take the id of user ids and perform a filter using the `IN` clause.

Perhaps adding your models and their relationships we can think about something better.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't know about `ids`. that's pretty cool

Comment: Not `@properties.where(user: @users)`? Or something like `User.includes(:properties).where(blah: blah)`?